# Cognito xray - segment not found issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, scala, aws-xray

I am trying to use x-ray with cognito:

```
val client: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider =
    AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withCredentials(keysConfig.credentialsProvider)
      .withRegion(config.region)
      .withClientConfiguration(new ClientConfiguration().withMaxErrorRetry(config.maxErrorRetries))
      .withRequestHandlers(new TracingHandler(AWSXRay.getGlobalRecorder))
      .build()
```

but I get bunch of errors:

> SEVERE: Suppressing AWS X-Ray context missing exception
> (SegmentNotFoundException): Failed to begin subsegment named
> 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider': segment cannot be found

I am doing it by an example from:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-awssdkclients.html[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-awssdkclients.html][1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-awssdkclients.html%5Bhttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-awssdkclients.html%5D%5B1%5D)

should I do some extra configuration in the aws xray UI ?

EDIT:
I tried also to remove manually adding request handler and just add a dependency: aws-xray-recorder-sdk-aws-sdk-instrumentor
but the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

Enabling AWS SDK instrumentation will automatically generate `subSegment` for your AWS calls. But in AWS Xray, the subSegment must be under an existing parent `segment` else will get SegmentNotFoundException.

Could you try to wrap your AWS calls with beginSegment() and endSegement()?

```
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay;
import com.amazonaws.xray.entities.Segment;

try {
    segment = AWSXRay.beginSegment("your service name");
    // your AWS call
    AWSCognito.xxx
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    AWSXRay.endSegment();
}
```